# Pyomo ValueError: Error retrieving component

Tags: python, optimization, valueerror, pyomo

My code is the following:

```
from coopr.pyomo import *
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import math

model = ConcreteModel() 

model.days = RangeSet(1, 31)  #model.time)

T = model.days

M_b1_O_stored_T = Var(T,bounds=(0, None))



def obj_rule(model):
  return sum( M_b1_O_stored_T[i] for i in model.days )


model.funcobj = Objective( rule =obj_rule , sense=maximize)
```

*It shows the following error: ValueError: Error retrieving component IndexedVar[1]: The component has not been constructed.
Do anyone can please help me on this please? The constraints do not show problem, but the objective function is showing...*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to the site...

You neglected to put your variable "into the model" with the `model.` prefix.  Note my fix below in both the declaration and in your objective function.

```
from pyomo.environ import *

# from coopr.pyomo import *
# import numpy as np
# from scipy.optimize import minimize
# import math

model = ConcreteModel() 

model.days = RangeSet(1, 31)  #model.time)

# T = model.days

model.M_b1_O_stored_T = Var(model.days,bounds=(0, None))


def obj_rule(model):
  return sum( model.M_b1_O_stored_T[i] for i in model.days )


model.funcobj = Objective( rule =obj_rule , sense=maximize)
```